# In Firestore does an ordered query induce an additional read cost?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `foo` of 1000 documents where each document has a field `bar`, a number. If I do a query `db.collection('foo').orderBy("bar", "desc").limit(5)` how many reads will I be charged for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no additional charge for using an `orderBy` statement in your query, as the ordering of the results can be determined from the indexes. So Firestore doesn't have to read all documents in the collection to determine the value of `bar` in your scenario, it just needs to read the index for `bar`.

In fact, Firestore **never** needs to read all documents to satisfy a query. It's whole performance guarantee is based on being able to execute any query it allows by reading slices from indexes only.

---

You'll be charged for at least 1 and at most 5 reads by that query. The exact charge depends on how you implement the read operation, and the state of the local cache.

Things to keep in mind:

- If the client is not connected to the server, you will not be charged for any document reads.
- If a document is already in the cache of the client making the call, you may not be charged for reading it from the server.
- If there are no documents returned from the server for the query, you will still be charged 1 document read for the query itself. If any documents are returned from the server, there is no additional charge for the query.

Answer (score 0):

5 reads. You get charged for what you request which in this case is 5 due to `limit(5)` irrespective of amount of documents you have.

Read more at: [Understand Cloud Firestore Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations)